# Visiting the UK in the last three weeks of visa validity

Tags: visas, uk

I have valid visa up to 8 April 2018. I'm planning to visit UK mid-March for a week maximum.

Is it OK to make a journey in the last few weeks of my visa, provided that I make sure I book my plane back before the expiry date and have a business invitation for the particular week?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it is fine**, all you need to do is to convince the IO that you are genuinely seeking entry for that short time and for the purpose allowed and that you will go back on or before your visa expires.